Help with Yamaha VA-5 circuit design
I recently bought a Yamaha VA-5 guitar amplifier and, since there is no service manual online, I hope to:

create a correct circuit design (finished the paper version and now have a electronic version)
create a correct breadboard design using probably Fritzing.
build a breadboard with parts.
solder a solderable breadboard to make a working model.

I'm currently between (1) and (2) and I'm looking to make my circuit design better. I had some problems especially with the distortion switch design, probably also the headphones. I had to use a lot of external outputs since I could label those.
Anyway. Here it is. Hopefully I haven't made a big mess of things.
First attempt.
Second attempt.

Third attempt.

You have not asked a question that needs an answer. This is a Q&A site. Please add a question which you want answered.

Please familiarize yourself with this, and implement: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics

Wow. that bad...Back to the drawing board. Thanks for the input.

Being pedantic, you're not creating a "design", that's already been done by Yamaha. You're just creating a schematic diagram to represent their design.

Being even more pedantic, Yamaha didn't publish it...which makes "creating a design" an exercise in semantics.

Ok, I've done a revision. Hopefully I've nudged it a little toward "better". One main question I have is how the VCC+ and GND lines intersect with the components, it just feels like something is wrong. Also the transistor in the sound manipulation stage might be an op-amp...maybe I should draw it differently. Also still unsure that the distortion switch is correct.

Next, you can do a very simple major cleanup. Use GND symbols on every component pin connected to ground. Then remove all your ground nets. This will eliminate a load of clutter and make it really obvious what is grounded. Post the result and convert the current schematic to an image link (as I did with your first schematic) so that anyone trying to follow your improvements can look them up.

ah ok. perfect thanks.

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

the circuit around R1 and R2 is incorrect

hiya jsotola: I asked a few questions in my last comment, mostly as to proper grounding but any comments (just like your R1/R2 comment) would go a long way in just making the schematic better or more precise. Since I'm working from a PCB and (for my skills) it's pretty complex, all the help I can get helps me move it forward. Thanks.

Right now I'm checking and marking all the grounds with a multimeter on the pcb. Update to come.

Added all grounds I could find on the pcb. Added a power supply switch. Tried to fix the R1/R2 circuit issue. Still pretty cluttery but maybe more accurate.

@William this is a Q&A site. Please ask a question you want answered. Posting project updates sounds more like you want to start a blog.

Hi @Justme: the specific question I would like answered is this: "are there any suggestions that people may have that would help improve my schematic?" I can understand that that is not a one-off, answer and done question. It is a question nontheless. If the question itself is bothersome, or the time it takes to answer it is too onerous, I will be okay with shoving off to somewhere better suited to my needs. In any case, thank you!

As a schematic, I have no doubt that it 100% correctly resembles the circuit in question.
However as the schematic is made by reverse-engineering a physical circuit, with parts placed wherever they happen to be on PCB and chips are just squares with a lot of pins on them.
So to anyone reading it, or using it for repairing the equipment, it is extremely difficult to see what the circuit is supposed to do and how it will do it.
The components should be grouped and organized into logical blocks, which may even require that chips are not just blocks with pins but expanded into separate submodules like the op-amp chip contains two op-amps and single set of power supply pins.
